# Duda sobre diccionarios en Python

Tags: python, diccionarios

¿Cuál es el propósito de `p` en el diccionario?

```
p = Clase()
for c in diccionario.keys():
  if variable == c:
    diccionario[c](p)
```

Comment: Según entiendo, cada elemento del diccionario es una función, y `p` es el argumento que se le pasa a esa función.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El paréntesis de `(p)` indica una **llamada** a algún tipo "callable" (como una función, método, clase...) o a una instancia de clase  que tenga definido el método  `__call__`. A la vez que se llama se le **pasa la instancia `p` como argumento**. Por lo tanto el diccionario debe tener como valores algo que pueda ser llamado y que acepte como mínimo un argumento.

Para saber exactamente que hace tu código haría falta más contexto, como el contenido de `diccionario`, la definición de `Clase`, etc. Pero podemos crear un ejemplo reproducible para explicar la idea:

```
class Clase:
    pass

# Función que recibe un argumento y lo imprime:
def foo(arg):
    print("Función foo ha sido llamada con argumento {}.".format(arg))

# Clase con instancias callables:
class Bar:
    def __call__(self, arg):
        print("Instancia de Bar ha sido llamada con argumento {}.".format(arg))

diccionario = {"a": print,  "b": foo,  "c": Bar()}
p = Clase()

variable = "a"
for c in diccionario.keys():
    if variable == c:
        diccionario[variable](p)

variable = "b"
for c in diccionario.keys():
    if variable == c:
        diccionario[c](p)

variable = "c"
for c in diccionario.keys():
    if variable == c:
        diccionario[c](p)
```

**Salida:**

> <__main__.Clase object at 0x7f0bcfbf23c8>
>   Función foo ha sido llamada con argumento <__main__.Clase object at 0x7f0bcfbf23c8>>.
>   Instancia de Bar ha sido llamada con argumento <__main__.Clase object at 0x7f0bcfbf23c8>.

---

Observa como la clave `"a"` del diccionario tiene como valor la función "built-in"· `print` (Python 3), la clave `"b"` nuestra función `foo` y la clave `"c"` una instancia de `Bar`.

Como se ve  `diccionario[c](p)` simplemente obtiene el valor asociado a la clave `c` y lo llama pasándole como argumento `p`:

- `diccionario["a"](p)`  es lo mismo que  `print(p)`
- `diccionario["b"](p)`  es lo mismo que  `foo(p)`
- `diccionario["c"](p)`  es lo mismo que  `Bar()(p)`

A todo esto, **el `for` carece de sentido en este caso**. Las claves de un diccionario son únicas, dado que solo hay una clave (de existir) igual al valor de `variable`, en vez de iterar sobre ellas basta con un simple condicional, más simple y eficiente:

```
if variable in diccionario:
    diccionario[variable](p)
```

Volviendo a tu pregunta concreta, `p` no tiene ningún propósito con relación al diccionario más allá de ser el argumento a pasar a sus valores "callables" cuando son llamados.